# Python match records where elements are the same but dollars are within %

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying kickout exceptions from a s/s where most if not all elements match, with the exception of the dollar amounts associated with the record.  So if for example, Column A - Column C match, but the dollar difference between the two is 10% or less, i would like to create logic to only highlight these examples within a dataframe.  And i would need this for any example where this happens, not just a static id.
S/S:

```
Client ID(Numeric) Client_2nd_ID(Alphanumeric) Instrument(text)  Dollars(numer)
12345              FA000123AB                  Baseball          600
45678              PP000157DC                  Football          800
12345              FA000123AB                  Baseball          570
12345              FA000123AB                  Baseball          645
12345              FB000159EE                  Baseball          605
```

Using the above example, I would like the dataframe to only show the three records for Client ID: 12345, 2nd_ID FA000123AB, instrument Baseball and Dollars 600,570,645 and as i mentioned any other situation where there are similarities for other record instances not including the above mentioned ID examples (making this variable vs static)

Comment: You would need a reference dollar value to compare with to see if you are in the 1% range. Which is? First row? The average value of the column? If you have different groups (like half of the values are close between themself, the other half are close between themselfes but far from the first half, is going to be difficult).

Comment: Yeah, i agree with your thoughts- i know i can bucket groups of records by their various ID matches and then i would need to look at which ones are within 1% of each other in dollars, but i am drawing a blank as to how to do the second part or how to represent the quantitative logic

Comment: That is because your request, as it is, is bad written. Grouping requires exact values, not "close" values. Let me explain with an example. `a` and `b` are close (whatever criterion you may use to define close, doesn't matter now). `b` and `c` are close. But turns out that `a` and `c` are not close. How do you group them? Simply, you can't. The concept of "closeness" lacks transitive property.

Comment: What i meant was, using a group by or pivot function to group by Client id, Client 2nd ID and instrument and then somehow using logic to determine what if any records using the 'Dollars' column are within 1% of each other

Comment: So, do you want to verify if **all** those with same ID, 2nd ID and instrument have dollar value within 1%?

Comment: my mistake, i wrote 1%, i meant 10%- my apologies- the ideal output would be records 1, 3, 4 because their client id, client 2nd id, and instrument are the same and their dollars are within 10% of each other (possibly not 10% of each record, but between the group one is at least within 10% of another in the grouping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will filter any records within group client/instrument which "Dollars" field value has difference less than a threshold with a closest value within the group:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

threshold = 0.01

df = pd.DataFrame({'Client_ID': [12345, 45678, 12345, 12345, 12345],
                    'Client_2nd_ID': ["FA000123AB", "PP000157DC", "FA000123AB", "FA000123AB", "FB000159EE"],
                    'Instrument': ["Baseball", "Football", "Baseball", "Baseball", "Baseball"],
                    'Dollars': [600, 800, 570, 645, 605]})

idx_lookup = df.apply(lambda x: (df.loc[(df['Client_ID'] == x['Client_ID']) & (df['Instrument'] == x['Instrument'] ), 'Dollars'] - x['Dollars']).abs().replace(0, np.nan).idxmin(), axis=1)

df['percent'] = (df['Dollars'] - df.loc[idx_lookup, 'Dollars'].values) / df.loc[idx_lookup, 'Dollars'].values

df = df.drop(df[(df.percent<=threshold) & (df.percent>0)].index)
```

[image]

It looks like it matches your criteria for client #12345, however, I checked additionally by adding 805 values for client #45678 to make sure it works correct for different clients:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

threshold = 0.01

df = pd.DataFrame({'Client_ID': [12345, 45678, 12345, 12345, 12345, 45678],
                    'Client_2nd_ID': ["FA000123AB", "PP000157DC", "FA000123AB", "FA000123AB", "FB000159EE", "PP000157DC"],
                    'Instrument': ["Baseball", "Football", "Baseball", "Baseball", "Baseball", "Football" ],
                    'Dollars': [600, 800, 570, 645, 605, 805]})

idx_lookup = df.apply(lambda x: (df.loc[(df['Client_ID'] == x['Client_ID']) & (df['Instrument'] == x['Instrument'] ), 'Dollars'] - x['Dollars']).abs().replace(0, np.nan).idxmin(), axis=1)

df['percent'] = (df['Dollars'] - df.loc[idx_lookup, 'Dollars'].values) / df.loc[idx_lookup, 'Dollars'].values

df = df.drop(df[(df.percent<=threshold) & (df.percent>0)].index)
```

[image]

Comment: Absolute GENIUS!  Thank you Stepan, I appreciate your help so much!